# Bad request on oauth/token

Tags: docusignapi

I try to use JWT Authentication but the API returns 400 Bad request {"error":"invalid_request"}.

Headers :

```
POST https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
```

Body :

```
grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion=XXXX
```

The JWT token is well formatted and contains as body :

```
iss = _clientIntegratorKey,
sub = "628c4cc3-d36e-4a6b-80bf-b7ccb97d842c",
iat = (long)(now - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds,
exp = (long)(now.AddSeconds(3600) - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds,
aud = "account-d.docusign.com",
scope = "signature"
```

What am i missing ?

Comment: Are you using Admin or User Consent?, and I would propose to first try creating assertion using jwt.io/ website and running API using POSTMAN before coding it. Normally I have see issues in iat and exp as DS expects value differently compare to any other library.

Comment: I used user consent and my jwt seems to be well formatted via jwt.io. Also, the iat and exp looks good :(

Comment: Did you try putting assertion in Postman to test it instead of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used my own RSA function that not encrypt with the right cypher algorithm.

Now I use a library (c# dotnet core : RSACryptoServiceProvider) to do it and it works like a charm.